# How do I prevent selection of data outside my selected range from highlighting when using crossfilter.js?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I'm new to crossfilter.js. Whenever I used the range selector I get the strange blocky highlighted area on my bar chart outside of my filter range. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

How I can prevent this blocky section from highlighting outside my range?

[image: Crossfilter strange bar selection]

```
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.conf = d3.round(+d.Conf,1);
        console.log(d.conf);

    });

    var facts = crossfilter(data); // Put data into crossfilter

    var confDim = facts.dimension(function (d) { return d.conf;}); // conf # filter
    var confTotal = confDim.group().reduceCount(function (d) { return d.conf;});

    var confChart = dc.barChart("#conf-chart");

    confChart
        .width(500).height(200)
        .dimension(confDim)
        .group(confTotal,"Confidence Number")
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,5]).range([10,400]))
        .yAxisLabel("Number of data points")
        .brushOn(true);

    dc.renderAll();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line that you've commented as being a filter is actually just setting up the dimension in its entirety:

```
var confDim = facts.dimension(function (d) { return d.conf;}); // conf # filter
```

You need to define a filter using one of the filter functions.  See the documentation [here](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_filter).

Be careful to read the documentation for [dimension.group](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_group) carefully as it contains a gotcha where the filter on the dimension being grouped won't be applied.  To work around this you may need to actually define 2 dimensions that are identical and use one for filtering and the other for grouping.